# Render video of world map with routes between geographical positions

Tags: .net, video, geolocation

I want to render a video with the world map as background and geographical routes plotted as the video plays.

I'm comfortable with C#, so I can bake an shake the data and gather the the positions in my routes.

What I need help with is what software I can use that I use to render the video and feed with data through XML or something to plot the routes.

If there aren't any software available, are there any way to do this using GDI, WPF or anything remotely related to .NET? Actually, I would like to do it in WPF, but I beleive WPF can't handle the amount of routes I want to render. I need to render about 200.000 routes.

I could stretch to HTML5, if there is a chance this could be handled using that, but I don't think there's a chance this can be handled using anything but pre rendered things.

Comment: You want to render 200,000 routes on a single image so that they all display at the same time?

Comment: Well, not in a single image - a video. And I want to animate them so that they go from A to B. I might want to fade them once they have reached their destination so to speak. Or maybe just increase opacity. I know 200k is a big number and that's why I think I need to render this in a video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [Google Earth](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/) to plot the routes, adding and removing as you go?

Comment: I want to try and have them lying around, but fading them. I think that might be a pretty nice effect. Note that this is supposed to be good looking rather than usable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with GDI or possibly WPF to render each frame, and then use [Splicer](http://splicer.codeplex.com/) to put the frames together into a video.